# Strange behaviour when naming variable in lowerCamelCase

Tags: ios, swift

I came across a strange behaviour in Swift while programming a Master-Detail application.

**Here's the scenario**:
It's a simple Task Manager application. I have two text controls (**TaskName**, **TaskDescription**) on the TaskDetailView and two string variables with the same name but in lowerCamelCase (**taskName**, **taskDescription**) declared in the TaskDetailViewController.

```
@IBOutlet var TaskName:UITextField!         //UpperCamelCase
@IBOutlet var TaskDescription:UITextView!   //UpperCamelCase
var taskName:String?                        //lowerCamelCase
var taskDescription:String?                 //lowerCamelCase
```

I am setting the values of Text controls on ViewDidLoad() as usual:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TaskName.text = taskName
    TaskDescription.text = taskDescription
}
```

And I am passing the data in prepareForSegue (from TaskListViewController) as usual:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segue.identifier == "TaskListSegue"){
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ToDoTaskViewController
        let (task, desc) = m_ToDoListManager.GetTask(TaskListView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row)
        println("selected \(task) \(desc)")
        detailViewController.taskName = task
        detailViewController.taskDescription = desc
    }
}
```

The way everything is implemented is correct. 
But now when you run the application, the values of text controls are not set.
In fact, the values of the variables also are not set.

**What must be happening here?** 
I have already investigated this problem and also came up with a solution (see my answer below). Please also see Martin R's answer below for a detailed explanation. I just wanted to share this with everyone. I am not sure if anyone has come across this issue.

**Update:**
Here's the actual code:https://github.com/Abbyjeet/Swift-ToDoList

Comment: 1. Variables should start with a lower case letter. 2. Name the variables better to prevent confusion, perhaps name the IBOutlet `taskNameTextField` to be clear what it is and distinguish it from the ivar `taskName`.

Comment: could you paste the whole project to github? this looks like an interesting issue I would like to inspect.

Comment: @Zaph Agree with your suggestion and that's what I always follow. I was experimenting with Swift. So I was little lazy and came across this issue.

Comment: @Sulthan I have shared the code at Github (see the update in the question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

- Your Swift class is (ultimately) a subclass of `NSObject`.
- Therefore the properties are Objective-C properties with getter and setter method.
- The name of the setter method for a property is built by *capitalizing* the first
  letter of the property name, e.g. property "foo" has the setter method `setFoo:`

As a consequence, the setter method for *both* properties `TaskName` and `taskName` is called `setTaskName:`.

In an Objective-C file, you would get a compiler error

> synthesized properties 'taskName' and 'TaskName' both claim setter 'setTaskName:' - use of this setter will cause unexpected behavior

but the Swift compiler does not notice the conflict.

A small demo of the problem:

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
    var prop : String?
    var Prop : String?
}

let mc = MyClass()
mc.prop = "foo"
mc.Prop = "bar"
println(mc.prop) // bar
println(mc.Prop) // nil
```

In your case

```
TaskName.text = ...
```

sets the "taskName" property, not the "TaskName". The properties have different type,
so that the behavior is undefined.

Note that the problem does *only* occur for "Objective-C compatible" properties. If you remove the
`NSObject` superclass in above example, the output is as expected.

**Conclusion:** You cannot have two Objective-C properties that differ only in the
case of the first letter. The Swift compiler should fail with an error here (as the
Objective-C compiler does).

Comment: I didn't know Obj-C compiler would fail there. Nice finding!

Comment: @martin-r Thanks! That is what I thought about if you see my own answer but I wasn't sure what it was. I liked your detailed explanation about under the hood things. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were facing with was not connected to the swift language. Method `prepareForSegue` is called before `loadView`. That mean `UITextField` and `UITextView` are not initialized yet. That's why fields were not initialized.

You also asked: Why compiler doesn't show any error? That's because any selector performed on nil object doesn't throw an exception. So for example (sorry for obj-c):

```
UITextField *tf = nil;
[tf setText:@"NewText"];
```

Will not show any error.

As you said on your own answer to solve your problem you need to add additional fields to your destination controller (copy-paste):

```
var tAskName:String?                        //cUstomCamelCase
var tAskDescription:String?                 //cUstomCamelCase
```

Comment: He didn't use the outlets before `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Yes he does. In previous ViewController in prepareForSegue: method he access to that outlets

Comment: @Szu I agree with you but if I name the same variable as tAskName instead of taskName, it works! Also I have access to destinationViewController in prepareForSegue and these variables are part of that Controller and I can set their values.

Comment: @Szu No, he is accessing the outlets only in `viewDidLoad` which is the correct thing to do. In `prepareForSeque` he is accessing only a property. That's a common pattern.

Comment: @Sulthan okey. I read 2 more times his quiestion and now undestand. As you said that might be an interesting issue.

Answer (score -2):

**Why is it happening?**
I believe that internally Swift is using lowerCamelCase for text controls names which are not yet initialized and thus failing to set the values. But it is also strange that I didn't get any kind of error.

**How did I solve it?**
I know that the Swift is case-sensitive. So that was not the issue. So I just changed the case of one letter and named the variables as (**tAskName**, **tAskDescription**) and the values were set as expected.

```
@IBOutlet var TaskName:UITextField!         //UpperCamelCase
@IBOutlet var TaskDescription:UITextView!   //UpperCamelCase
var tAskName:String?                        //cUstomCamelCase
var tAskDescription:String?                 //cUstomCamelCase
```

So the conclusion is that if I have a control named **TaskName**, I cannot have a variable named as **taskName**

Comment: You should move your doubts (last paragraph) to your question.

Comment: @Szu I am just conforming to StackOverflow's format. I have already resolved the issue.

Comment: This answer is speculation that perhaps worked simply by coincidence. Further `TaskName` is just an ivar.